# Convert Excel to xml by C# in specified xml format

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to convert my excel file into XML format .
I have found various ways on doing this on Stack Overflow. First, the technologies I'm using are: ASP.NET MVC 4.0 with WCF REST service in C#.

Excel file
Excel file

| No | Model Year | Make | Model | Engine Size (liters) | Test Group Name | Certification Level | Weight Class | Exhaust Type | Converter Type | Total Converter | Monitored Converter | Conv. Location | Converter Part Type | MFR Part Number | Application Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1996 | Acura | Integra | 1.8 | THN1.8VJGFFK | TIER1 | PC | S | TWC | 1 | 1 | U | DIRECT FIT | 251001 | ALL |
| 2 | 1994 | Acura | Integra | 2.8 | THN1.8VJGFFK | TIER1 | PC | S | TWC | 1 | 1 | U | DIRECT FIT | 251041 | ALL |
| 3 | 1995 | Acura | Integra | 3.8 | THN1.8VJGFFK | TIER1 | PC | S | TWC | 1 | 1 | U | DIRECT FIT | 251041 | ALL |

Desire xml Output:

```xml
<tns:PART>
    <tns:am_mfr_code>CONV</tns:am_mfr_code>
    <tns:part_type>Pre</tns:part_type>
    <tns:CATALYST_INFORMATION>
        <tns:converter_series>20000</tns:converter_series>
        <tns:cat_part_type>DIRECT FIT</tns:cat_part_type>
        <tns:mfr_part_number>251001</tns:mfr_part_number>
    </tns:CATALYST_INFORMATION>
    <tns:VEHICLE_INFORMATION>
        <tns:make>Acura</tns:make>
        <tns:model>Integra</tns:model>
        <tns:model_year>1996</tns:model_year>
        <tns:BaseVehicleId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <tns:test_group_name>THN1.8VJGFFK</tns:test_group_name>
        <tns:displacement_ldv>1.8</tns:displacement_ldv>
        <tns:application_type>ALL</tns:application_type>
        <tns:carb_ftp_std>TIER1</tns:carb_ftp_std>
        <tns:vehicle_class_code>PC</tns:vehicle_class_code>
        <tns:total_atd_number>1</tns:total_atd_number>
        <tns:catalyst_type_am>TWC</tns:catalyst_type_am>
        <tns:exhaust_type>S</tns:exhaust_type>
        <tns:catalyst_location>U</tns:catalyst_location>
        <tns:monitored_converters>1</tns:monitored_converters>
    </tns:VEHICLE_INFORMATION>
</tns:PART>
<tns:PART>
    <tns:am_mfr_code>CONV</tns:am_mfr_code>
    <tns:part_type>Pre</tns:part_type>
    <tns:CATALYST_INFORMATION>
        <tns:converter_series>20000</tns:converter_series>
        <tns:cat_part_type>UNIVERSAL</tns:cat_part_type>
        <tns:mfr_part_number>251041</tns:mfr_part_number>
    </tns:CATALYST_INFORMATION>
    <tns:VEHICLE_INFORMATION>
        <tns:make>Acura</tns:make>
        <tns:model>Integra</tns:model>
        <tns:model_year>1996</tns:model_year>
        <tns:BaseVehicleId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <tns:test_group_name>THN1.8VJGFFK</tns:test_group_name>
        <tns:displacement_ldv>2</tns:displacement_ldv>
        <tns:application_type>ALL</tns:application_type>
        <tns:carb_ftp_std>TIER1</tns:carb_ftp_std>
        <tns:vehicle_class_code>PC</tns:vehicle_class_code>
        <tns:total_atd_number>1</tns:total_atd_number>
        <tns:catalyst_type_am>TWC</tns:catalyst_type_am>
        <tns:exhaust_type>S</tns:exhaust_type>
        <tns:catalyst_location>U</tns:catalyst_location>
        <tns:monitored_converters>1</tns:monitored_converters>
    </tns:VEHICLE_INFORMATION>
    <tns:VEHICLE_INFORMATION>
        <tns:make>Acura</tns:make>
        <tns:model>RL</tns:model>
        <tns:model_year>1996</tns:model_year>
        <tns:BaseVehicleId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <tns:test_group_name>THN3.5VJGKEK</tns:test_group_name>
        <tns:displacement_ldv>3.5</tns:displacement_ldv>
        <tns:application_type>ALL</tns:application_type>
        <tns:carb_ftp_std>TIER1</tns:carb_ftp_std>
        <tns:vehicle_class_code>PC</tns:vehicle_class_code>
        <tns:total_atd_number>1</tns:total_atd_number>
        <tns:catalyst_type_am>TWC</tns:catalyst_type_am>
        <tns:exhaust_type>S</tns:exhaust_type>
        <tns:catalyst_location>U</tns:catalyst_location>
        <tns:monitored_converters>1</tns:monitored_converters>
    </tns:VEHICLE_INFORMATION>
</tns:PART>
```

I have tried to use Convert Excel to XML method, but I can't get the desire output as I want. Is there any other workaround solution convert from excel to desired output XML? I want exactly same as desired output.

```
            while (i <= oItem)
            {
                        XmlElement dobEle = doc.CreateElement("tns", "PART", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement am_mfr_code = doc.CreateElement("tns", "am_mfr_code", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement part_type = doc.CreateElement("tns", "part_type", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement CATALYST_INFORMATION = doc.CreateElement("tns", "CATALYST_INFORMATION", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement converter_series = doc.CreateElement("tns", "converter_series", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement cat_part_type = doc.CreateElement("tns", "cat_part_type", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement mfr_part_number = doc.CreateElement("tns", "mfr_part_number", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");

                        am_mfr_code.InnerText = "CONV";
                        string part_type1 = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
                        part_type.InnerText = part_type1;

                        string converter_series1 = text2.Text;
                        converter_series.InnerText = converter_series1;
                        cat_part_type.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[13].ToString();
                        mfr_part_number.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[14].ToString();

                        CATALYST_INFORMATION.AppendChild(converter_series);
                        CATALYST_INFORMATION.AppendChild(cat_part_type);
                        CATALYST_INFORMATION.AppendChild(mfr_part_number);

                        dobEle.AppendChild(am_mfr_code);
                        dobEle.AppendChild(part_type);
                        dobEle.AppendChild(CATALYST_INFORMATION);

                        XmlElement VEHICLE_INFORMATION = doc.CreateElement("tns", "VEHICLE_INFORMATION", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement make = doc.CreateElement("tns", "make", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement model = doc.CreateElement("tns", "model", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement model_year = doc.CreateElement("tns", "model_year", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement BaseVehicleId = doc.CreateElement("tns", "BaseVehicleId", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        BaseVehicleId.SetAttribute("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "true");
                        XmlElement Test_Group_Name = doc.CreateElement("tns", "test_group_name", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Engine = doc.CreateElement("tns", "displacement_ldv", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Application_Type = doc.CreateElement("tns", "application_type", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Certification_Level = doc.CreateElement("tns", "carb_ftp_std", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Weight_Class = doc.CreateElement("tns", "vehicle_class_code", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Total_Converter = doc.CreateElement("tns", "total_atd_number", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Converter_Type = doc.CreateElement("tns", "catalyst_type_am", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Exhaust_Type = doc.CreateElement("tns", "exhaust_type", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Conv_Location = doc.CreateElement("tns", "catalyst_location", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");
                        XmlElement Monitored_Converter = doc.CreateElement("tns", "monitored_converters", "http://www.arb.ca.gov");

                        make.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                        model.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                        model_year.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                        Test_Group_Name.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();
                        Engine.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                        Application_Type.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[15].ToString();
                        Certification_Level.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[6].ToString();
                        Weight_Class.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString();
                        Total_Converter.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[10].ToString();
                        Converter_Type.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[9].ToString();
                        Exhaust_Type.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[8].ToString();
                        Conv_Location.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[12].ToString();
                        Monitored_Converter.InnerText = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[11].ToString();


                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(make);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(model);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(model);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(model_year);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(BaseVehicleId);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Test_Group_Name);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Engine);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Application_Type);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Certification_Level);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Weight_Class);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Total_Converter);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Converter_Type);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Exhaust_Type);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Conv_Location);
                        VEHICLE_INFORMATION.AppendChild(Monitored_Converter);


                        dobEle.AppendChild(VEHICLE_INFORMATION);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(dobEle);
                i += 1;
            }

           
            doc.Save(Page.Server.MapPath("~/Data/output.xml"));
            Page.Response.Write("Created Successfuly");
            Page.Response.Clear();
            Page.Response.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
            Page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=Output.xml");
            Page.Response.TransmitFile(Page.Server.MapPath("~/Data/Output.xml"));
            Page.Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: The xml is not valid since there is no namespace with a URL for 'tns'.  You must add the namespace.  The second issue is the XML is not well formed and the Net Library requires special handling of this type of xml.  Well formed Xml has only one root tag.  Your xml has an array of PART at the root.  Add the URL for tns and see if you get correct results.  If not, post what you are actually getting.